# unable to launch any program: trap int3 ip error

Tags: kernel, dmesg, trap

I cannot launch any program in my desktop environment. I get these errors in `dmesg`:

```
traps: terminator[3670] trap int3 ip:374dda71261 sp:388624bbec0 error:0
traps: pcmanfm[3685] trap int3 ip:380699ca261 sp:3e15d350150 error:0
traps: audacious[3687] trap int3 ip:3636d699261 sp:3a18365ccb0 error:0
```

what do those messages mean, and how can I fix it ?

Everything worked until recently. I suspect it broke after regular update (`apt-get upgrade`). I am using Debian Stretch and LXDE as desktop environment.

Comment: I am not sure why you get this since you claim to be running a stable version, these should never occur in stable versions. Have you changed anything in `/etc/apt/sources.conf.d` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like prroblems caused by  filesystem / hdd failure

Answer (score 3):

These are not really errors, they are "break points" set by developers. What this means is that a developer set a break point in his program somewhere, and once the code reaches that point, you get a trap int3 message.

I doubt these are preventing you from launching other programs, however, this does mean that you have somehow installed a development version of the programs in question.